# Hydration error when using Image tag in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am working on a project using next.js
I am stuck on the following problem when using Image tag provided by Next.js.

My code is

```
{projects.map((el) => (
      <SwiperSlide key={el.id}>
        <div className='max-w-sm mx-auto bg-gray-800 bg-opacity-10 shadow-lg p-4 rounded-xl'>
          <div className='overflow-hidden h-56 rounded-xl'>
            <Image
              objectFit='cover'
              src={el.src}
              layout='responsive'
              alt=''
            />
          </div>
          <Heading2 color={`text-white my-5 text-left`}>
            {el.title}
          </Heading2>
          <div className='space-x-4'>
            <Link href='path'>
              <a className={buttonClass + " " + " bg-gray-800"}>Github</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href='path'>
              <a className={buttonClass + " " + "border border-gray-800 "}>
                Live Website
              </a>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </SwiperSlide>
    ))}
```

I am fetching the Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

But when I replace the Image tag with img tag then it works fine.

Comment: Where is `Image` coming from? `next/image`?

Comment: yes from next/image